# How to fix 'HTML5 currentTime always sets to zero'

Tags: reactjs

I am building a videoplayer in reactjs.I have my custom sliderbar.When I click on the sliderbar,I am getting the value of the sliderbar and calculating current time of the video and setting the currenttime using document.getElementById('video').currentTime = value.

But each time when I give an input to sliderbar,the video current time is setted to 0.

But this works fine in firefox with a warning message "The Operation was aborted"
It not working in chrome.

```
const pos = this.seek_bar.value;
this.video = document.getElementById("video");

let new_time = (pos / 100) * this.video.duration;

if (!isNaN(new_time)) this.video.currentTime = new_time;


this.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
  let value = (this.video.currentTime / this.video.duration) * 100;
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
     this.seek_bar.value = value;
  }
});
```

I want the chrome to set the current time I provide.Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Got It.

The problem was with streaming the video from server.
Changed the existing code to

```
video(req, res) {
const videoPath = req.query.videoPath;
const stat = fs.statSync(videoPath);
const fileSize = stat.size;
const range = req.headers.range;
if (range) {
  const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
  const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
  const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;
  const chunksize = end - start + 1;
  const file = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
  const head = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": chunksize,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  };
  res.writeHead(206, head);
  file.pipe(res);
} else {
  const head = {
    "Content-Length": fileSize,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
  };

  res.writeHead(200, head);
  fs.createReadStream(videoPath).pipe(res);
}
```

}